# Use nextjs to render a specific part of html page

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use nextjs for just a part of my web-site.
The navbar already exists in other frameworks, not even react. i want to use nextjs in a `<div id="nextjs_div">...</div>`, ie. just a part of my website.

The problem is that nextjs renders a whole HTML page with head and body components. so what I want basically is to delete these components and render just one div that will be mounted in my page.

I tried to modify the `page/_document` but couldn't succeed.

Do you have an idea of how i can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm mostly writing this for anyone coming here from Google as I hope/doubt OP is still having this problem 3 years later.

There are two possible use cases here:

1. Using NextJS as a templating/component framework to enable the use of JSX and server-side rendering to create partial HTML documents
2. The use of NextJS as a React server and create partial HTML documents which are themselves reactive on the client.

Use case 1 is doable and relatively simple, if a bit hacky, but is not a supported use case for NextJS.

Use case 2 is going to involve using the code below as a jumping off point. My recommendation is to replace `renderToStaticMarkup` with `renderToString` and then start researching how NextJS does React hydration because you're going to have to do it yourself. Legitimately, if there is anything you can do to avoid needing to do this, please just use React.

To render partial HTML documents using NextJS, you need to use the api handlers via the pages router and `renderToStaticMarkup`. If you use `renderToStaticMarkup` with the app router, it will complain.

File `./src/pages/test.tsx`:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server'

export default handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<string>
): void => {
  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    return void res.status(405)
      .send(`Only GET requests are allowed on this endpoint`)
  }

  const jsxElement = <div id="nextjs_div">Test</div>
  const plaintextHtml = renderToStaticMarkup(jsxElement)
  res.status(200).send(plaintextHtml)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next.js is a framework intended to create full pages and most likely not appropriate tool to use for creating a part of a page. You could use just React then.

If you can make an HTML from the navbar then you could insert it into Next.js project.

See [Add HTML header to Document.js example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60362264/5964023)